# Can't find SBT-shell in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt-plugin

Facing some issue with the build, I deleted the `project` and `.idea` directories of my SBT project (containing `submodules`) followed by `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` (invalidated the cache too)

Ever since relaunch of `IntelliJ`, I can't locate the `sbt shell`
[image]

Interestingly, I'm still getting the `sbt shell` when I open my other projects (in which I didn't delete the `project` and `.idea` directories) in `IntelliJ`
[image]

I can confirm that I have the latest release of `IntelliJ IDEA` for `MacOS` with the Scala plugin installed
[image]
[image]

Comment: Here's the [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000786124-Unable-to-find-sbt-shell) to my issue on JetBrains forums

Comment: besides shift+12, you can also try shift+ctrl/cmd+s, or action search for "sbt shell"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select

> Window → Restore Default layout

Or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

[image]

This will restore your default window layout and the tab will be visible again (You can check this works by hiding the *sbt* tab by right clicking and selecting 'Remove From Sidebar').

Some windows such as Maven or Ant need to be brought back by

> View → ToolWindows  → [Window Name]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Vojtech, that worked.
While the hidden sbt-shell reappeared, I had tried hiding the ant tab from sidebar (instead of sbt tab suggested by you) but that didn't come back.

Comment: Though I was able to get back the ant-build tab in sidebar from View > Tool Windows > Ant Build. Oddly enough, after restoring default layout, the SBT Shell option also appeared in this menu (which had gone missing before)

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 14):

what fixed my problem was:

- install scala plugin
- restart
- file -> close project
- instead of open, click new project, select scala with sbt option,
  then next
- select the same project as location.

hope it will save you time and energy

Answer (score 8):

In Intellij 2018, under `Preferences - Build, Execution, Deployment - Build Tools - sbt`, check "`Use sbt shell for build and import (requires sbt 0.13.5+)`". Then restart Intellij. The sbt shell tool window tab will appear in the bottom pane (if not, select it from `View - Tool Windows - sbt shell`).

Comment: I had it under `File - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Build Tools - sbt`

Answer (score 4):

In my case, scala plugin needed to be updated and accordingly this caused sbt to disappear from build tools. 
Go to `Settings --> Plugins --> Updates` and make sure that scala plugin is updated. If it wasn't and you updated it, you should restart the IDE afterwards.
After that removing the .idea folder and reimporting the project was necessary for the project to build.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I enabled the sbt shell going to "File - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Build Tools - sbt " and after enabling here, you need to restart your intellij and then you can find sbt-shell here "view- Tool window - sbt shell"

Comment: Just a restart after installing the Scala plugin did it for me.